# Resizing windows with keyboard shortcuts

Tags: resize

I have seen some people resizing their windows very efficiently with shortcuts..
For example window is on full screen then you press some key and it becomes the left side of the screen then another window you press a button and it takes the right side of the screen.

I'm not sure if this is achieved with any application or it's built in, does anyone know how to achieve that?

Comment: There are no global settings. Such possibility depends on the desktop environment. Which one are you running?

Comment: There are [quite a few useful keyboard shortcuts available](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-keyboard-shortcuts.html.en) 

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Ubuntu, some keyboard shortcuts are set up by default:

- **Maximize window**: <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>
- **Restore window**: <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>
- **Tile to left half of the screen**:  <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>
- **Tile to right half of the screen**:  <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>

In addition, keys are set up to move and resize using the keyboard:

- **Begin move**:  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>. After hitting this key, <kbd>arrow</kbd> keys will move the window, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> keys will quickly move the window toward the side of the screen or the edge of another window. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or another key when done
- **Begin resize**: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> will initiate a resize. <kbd>arrow</kbd> keys will resize the window, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> keys will resize towards the edge or another window.

Using hidden configuration settings, more custom shortcuts for window manipulation can be defined. The following configuration commands will set up shortcut keys for:

**• centering a window or moving it quickly to the side of the screen**

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-center "['<Control><Super>c']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-side-e "['<Control><Super>Right']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-side-n "['<Control><Super>Up']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-side-s "['<Control><Super>Down']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-side-w "['<Control><Super>Left']"
```

These are keybindings I defined. You can choose to use different keybindings by editing the commands first.

**• positioning a window in one of the corners of the screen**

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-corner-ne "['<Control><Super>2']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-corner-nw "['<Control><Super>1']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-corner-se "['<Control><Super>4']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-corner-sw "['<Control><Super>3']"
```

**• maximizing horizontally and vertically**

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings maximize-horizontally "['<Control><Super>equal']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings maximize-vertically "['<Control><Super>backslash']"
```

These settings can also be set using the utility `dconf-editor`.