# How to resize a popup?

Tags: 20.04, window, resize

Somehow, a recurring popup (the reminder for Evolution) got resized to full screen. Every time it appears, it takes up the full screen. How do I make it smaller again?

Things I have tried:

- Grabbing the edge of the window and resizing: Doesn't work, because I can't grab the edge of the window.
- Dragging the window away from the edge of the screen, as suggested on this official Ubuntu [help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-windows-maximize.html.en): Doesn't work, because I can't drag the window.
- Holding down super and then dragging the window, to be able to resize it, as suggested [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-windows-states.html.en): Doesn't work, because I still can't drag the window.
- Alt-F7 (move window via keyboard) and Alt-F8 (resize via keyboard), as suggested [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-windows-states.html.en): Neither has any effect.
- Super-Down as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1343891/resizing-windows-with-keyboard-shortcuts): Has no effect.
- Press Alt-Space and resize from system menu: Does not work, because "resize" is grayed out. (I can minimize the popup via this window, but that is not the desired behavior.)
- F11 as suggested in the comments: Has no effect.

My system: 20.04.3. Screenshot below. This is monitor #2 of a two-monitor setup. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You can take a screenshot with the `prt sc` key on the keyboard.

Comment: did you try F11 (the full screen button)?

Comment: Thank you, @ArchismanPanigrahi. Screenshot attached.

Comment: Thank you, @WU-TANG. I tried F11, and it has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the GNOME desktop environment, you can change the size of the popup window by going to the 'Windows tab in the 'Preferences window. In the 'Size & Position' section, you can change the 'Width' and 'Height' values to whatever you want. If you're using a different desktop environment, you may have to change the size of the popup window in a different way. You can try using some of these [popup banner designs](https://promolayer.io/%E3%81%8B%E3%81%94%E8%90%BD%E3%81%A1%E5%AF%BE%E7%AD%96/%E3%83%9D%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E3%83%90%E3%83%8A%E3%83%BC%E3%83%87%E3%82%B6%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3/). There you can find different ways to solve this problem with the popup size.